# Loop animation drawable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-drawable, animationdrawable

I'm trying to animate some png and i would loop the animation. This is my code:

```
wave.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.wave_animation);
                frameAnimation = (AnimationDrawable)wave.getBackground();
                frameAnimation.setCallback(wave);
                frameAnimation.setVisible(true, true);
                frameAnimation.start();
```

and here the xml with the png

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:oneshot="true">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_01" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_02" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_03" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_04" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

I added also the android:oneshot=false but doesn't work.

Answer (score 3):

just change `android:oneshot="false"` to be like this

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"  android:oneshot="false">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_01" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_02" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_03" android:duration="200" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/wave_04" android:duration="200" />
</animation-list>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code above shows

```
    android:oneshot="true"
```

Which will make your animation run Once and only Once.

You say you tried android:oneshot="false".
That will be essential for running through the animation-list more than once.  So put it back.

Keep in mind that running animation is a 'background' task which will terminate when the primary/foreground task completes regardless of its own settings.

If you want something else you might need to take a different approach.

Answer (score 0):

This is running an animation on image. Before starting the animation you need to make sure its not already running. Add a check before starting animation, if its running then stop it and then start it.

```
private void startAnimation(){

        imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.img_animation);

        AnimationDrawable imgAnimation = (AnimationDrawable) imageView.getDrawable();

        if (imgAnimation .isRunning()) {
            imgAnimation .stop();
        }
        imgAnimation .start();

    }
```

img_animation.xml // Check for comments in below

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:oneshot="true" >

    <!-- 24 frame per sec | 1000ms/24 i.e. 41ms per image -->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ball01" android:duration="41"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ball02" android:duration="41"/>
   ..........so on ..........
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ball24" android:duration="41"/>

     <!-- Reset to first when animation stops-->
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ball01"
        android:duration="10"/>

</animation-list>
```